# Plotting a closed interal function MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need a help. I have to generate a curve using MATLAB. The plot is defined by the formula (an analytic expression) :-

[image]

where, the meaning of the variables are as follows: R is the distributed resistive function, S is the distributive conductive function, k is the sheet resistance and *r(x,y)* is the distance between *
(x,y)*, and the perimeter *dl* with the integration made around all the perimeter of the chip.

A squared foil as shown in the figure with sides (a) 10 arbitrary units long and an unitary unit sheet resistance (k=1 ohm) is used for our consideration. The plot of the function *R(x,y)* is supposed to come out like this...

[image]

[image]

I literally have no clue how to plot this function. I could not even get the idea how to define the distance function *r(x,y)* with respect to *dl*. On top of that it is complicated further by the closed integral. Please help me. Any help in even simplifying the expression is also welcome. Is there any possible closed form expression for such a square structure ?

Thanks in advance. The link to the paper is here. [paper here](https://upcommons.upc.edu/e-prints/bitstream/2117/1486/1/S_1A_2.pdf)

Comment: You might want to add the link to the paper, as there is more information on the topic: https://upcommons.upc.edu/e-prints/bitstream/2117/1486/1/S_1A_2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reconstructing the math

The definition of the function `R` is not particularly clear, but I guess what they mean is:
[image: Integral definition]

With `dOmega` being the boundary of the foil and `p` a point `p = [px,py]` on the foil.

Imagine that for a point `p` on the sheet you are computing `R(p)` by going around the boundary of the foil (what they call the perimeter), your position being `q`, and integrating one divided by the distance from you (`q`) to the point `p` multiplied by `k`.

I guess you could analytically compute the integral for this rectangular sheet, but if you just want to plot the function, you could simply approximate the integral by defining a finite number of points on the boundary, evaluating the integrand in those points, then taking the mean and multiplying by the perimeter. [The same way you could approximate `integral(f(x), x=0...pi)` by `pi*(f(0)+f(pi/2)+f(pi))/3`]

**Alternative representation using coordinates:**

If you are only familiar with integrals along the real line in coordinate representation you could write this in the following way, which is frankly quite UGGGLY:
[image: Integral definition 2]

### Plotting an approximation

```
%% Config:
xlen = 10;
ylen = 10;
k = 1;

%% Setting up points on the boundary of the square
x = linspace(0,xlen,50);
y = linspace(0,ylen,50);
perimeter = 2*(xlen+ylen);
boundary = [x(1)*ones(length(y),1),   y'
            x', y(1)*ones(length(x),1); ...
            x(end)*ones(length(y),1), y'; ...         
            x', y(end)*ones(length(x),1)];

%% Function definition
norm2 = @(X) sqrt(sum(X.^2,2));
R = @(p) 1/(perimeter*mean(1./(k*norm2(bsxfun(@minus,boundary,p)))));

%% Plotting
[X_grid,Y_grid] = ndgrid(x,y);
R_grid = zeros(size(X_grid));
for ii = 1:length(x)
    for jj = 1:length(y)
        R_grid(ii,jj) = R([x(ii),y(jj)]);
    end
end
surf(X_grid, Y_grid, R_grid);
axis vis3d;
```

This will give you the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was wondering if you would kindly state how the boundary & the function R is defined in such a way so that we can get the entire area? I am not very clear about the bsxfun too.

Comment: The boundary are the four edge-lines: `{x=0, y=0..10}, {x=0..10, y=0}, {x=10, y=0..10}, {x=0..10, y=10}`, This I have directly tranlated into matlab, you can have a look at the points by plotting `plot(boundary(:,1),boundary(:,2),'.');`. The `bsxfun(@minus, boundary, p)` is just a fancy alternative for `[boundary(:,1)-p(1), boundary(:,2)-p(2)]`, which subtracts `p` from all boundary points at the same time. Using the `norm2` we are just calculating all distances to the boundary points simultaneously. I don't understand what you mean by *so that we can get the entire area*. We do already!

Comment: sorry about that. completely forgot.